# Signing XML document leaves a space between </ds:SignedInfo> and <ds:SignatureValue>

Tags: c#, .net, soap

Signing the XML document for soap leaves the two nodes with a blank space making it unrecognizable by the web service.

Example of current xml:

```
<ds:Reference URI="#TS">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512" />
                  <ds:DigestValue>JAwQ2xwwMbKSF5WV5y/F4ZNKvyD3ok5xvqOCZzcBbTiUKHcEAe8CMKQbAS6h0XHx+1An6BTM3eEhSQuINmT5lw==</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            THERES A HUGE SPACE HERE (Had to add text as Stackoverflow formats code..) <ds:SignatureValue>JMXA7QC3WJYeYNpk+AH36OBftJAD2zQdvX16Y/wZWNc9gaTemAoqtvNjvkn9FKyu7k8vpSTH+7c4q2x78QYI0iRLC2xRGLnwruoiXE+sNgvptdt5cbhV2eUe7AIsbOcJPMasDJ7ZnB341+oDnTCT/32ZBDm6Qh4ehtCflajdZjYN16m1xsmlDh6lKpf3O6ZYo9Y6SUNC+IGr7K5BwsoIBpD9rt/QaTPdjodod4nRJthJOYJW31RHXKsIWu8CqgXMmTY/oNSFipV09f7eSSqGrbhcKAGPd7aLdC02egFiDKmsA2zQfY9MuacBAnlrWq1GtSzM981cVFocTxcVLF6Cnw==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                  <wsse:Reference URI="#X509Token" />
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
         </ds:Signature>
      </wsse:Security>
```

expected output:

```
<ds:Reference URI="#TS">
              <ds:Transforms>
                 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
              </ds:Transforms>
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512" />
              <ds:DigestValue>JAwQ2xwwMbKSF5WV5y/F4ZNKvyD3ok5xvqOCZzcBbTiUKHcEAe8CMKQbAS6h0XHx+1An6BTM3eEhSQuINmT5lw==</ds:DigestValue>
           </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>JMXA7QC3WJYeYNpk+AH36OBftJAD2zQdvX16Y/wZWNc9gaTemAoqtvNjvkn9FKyu7k8vpSTH+7c4q2x78QYI0iRLC2xRGLnwruoiXE+sNgvptdt5cbhV2eUe7AIsbOcJPMasDJ7ZnB341+oDnTCT/32ZBDm6Qh4ehtCflajdZjYN16m1xsmlDh6lKpf3O6ZYo9Y6SUNC+IGr7K5BwsoIBpD9rt/QaTPdjodod4nRJthJOYJW31RHXKsIWu8CqgXMmTY/oNSFipV09f7eSSqGrbhcKAGPd7aLdC02egFiDKmsA2zQfY9MuacBAnlrWq1GtSzM981cVFocTxcVLF6Cnw==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
           <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
              <wsse:Reference URI="#X509Token" />
           </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
     </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
```

Code that signs the xmlDocument:

```
   public static void SignEnveloped(XmlDocument xmlDoc, XmlElement wsse, string certPassword, string certLocation)
        {
            MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(certPassword));
            string base64Result = Convert.ToBase64String(md5.Hash);
            // Format the document to ignore white spaces.
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

            SignedXmlWithId signedXml = new SignedXmlWithId(xmlDoc);
            X509Certificate2 uidCert2 = new X509Certificate2(certLocation, base64Result, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var exportedKeyMaterial = uidCert2.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
            var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24));
            key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);
            signedXml.SigningKey = key;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512";
            Reference referenceBody = new Reference();
            Reference referenceTime = new Reference();
            referenceBody.Uri = "#Body";
            referenceBody.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512";
            referenceTime.Uri = "#TS";
            referenceTime.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512";
            referenceBody.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            referenceTime.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            signedXml.AddReference(referenceBody);
            signedXml.AddReference(referenceTime);
            var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            XmlElement SecurityTokenReference = xmlDoc.CreateElement("wsse", "SecurityTokenReference", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

            XmlElement wsseReference = xmlDoc.CreateElement("wsse", "Reference", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
            wsseReference.SetAttribute("URI", "#X509Token");
            SecurityTokenReference.AppendChild(wsseReference);
            var keyInfoData = new KeyInfoNode(SecurityTokenReference);
            keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);
            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
                //Here we set the namespace prefix on the signature element and all child elements to "ds", invalidating the signature.
                AssignNameSpacePrefixToElementTree(xmlDigitalSignature, "ds");

                //So let's recompute the SignatureValue based on our new SignatureInfo...

                //For XPath
                XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"); //this prefix is arbitrary and used only for XPath

                XmlElement xmlSignedInfo = xmlDigitalSignature.SelectSingleNode("ds:SignedInfo", namespaceManager) as XmlElement;

                //Canonicalize the SignedInfo element
                XmlDsigC14NTransform transform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
                XmlDocument signedInfoDoc = new XmlDocument();
                signedInfoDoc.LoadXml(xmlSignedInfo.OuterXml);
                transform.LoadInput(signedInfoDoc);

                //Compute the new SignatureValue
                string signatureValue = Convert.ToBase64String(key.SignData(transform.GetOutput() as MemoryStream, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()));
                //Set it in the xml
                XmlElement xmlSignatureValue = xmlDigitalSignature.SelectSingleNode("ds:SignatureValue", namespaceManager) as XmlElement;
                xmlSignatureValue.InnerText = signatureValue;
                wsse.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));


        }
```

What I need help is how do I remove the unwanted huge space between the node signedInfo and SignatureValue as it makes the soap sign invalid with the whitespace (Seems the service is unable to decode with whitespace...)

Comment: Can you distill this down into an [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: did you find the answer to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of resolved, issue wasn't related to signedInfo causing a whitespace. Still haven't resolved it yet but have found the culprit.